# How to redirect all http traffic to https

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx and would like all http traffic to become https using nginx.
can someone post an example for nginx config file?

Here is mine. it's not working and i don't have a lot of nginx exprience:
https://github.com/oren/wiki/blob/master/dokuwiki.conf

Thanks!

Comment: thanks! i have a lot of lines in my config that are probably very specific to the wiki i use. can you point me toward a question/answer that is relevant to me?

Comment: i use something similar to http://serverfault.com/questions/636429/nginx-redirect-http-to-https and it's working. cheers.